# Updating values of a table for some users but leaving some rows untouched

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `purchases` having columns `id(int)`, `user(int)`, `priority(int)` and `timestamp(TIMESTAMP)`, and I would like to change the priority of purchases having value A, for certain arbitrary group of users, to some other value B, so that each `user` would have two of their newest purchases still untouched, and all older purchases changed to value B.

How would I do it using SQL?

A query like:

```
UPDATE purchases 
SET priority = @newpriority 
WHERE user IN (@usergroup) 
AND priority = @oldpriority 
GROUP BY user 
HAVING count(*) > 2
```

would change all rows for users having more than 2 rows with that priority, but I want to leave two newest purhcases untouched.

Comment: can you please post input and expected output ?

Comment: add condition on timestamp

Comment: What kind of condition for timestamp @KP.

Comment: I would say, USe row_number and  order by timestamp desc, And update row_number >2

Comment: @Tohveli, Try my answer and let me know whether it is selecting older purchase except latest 2 new purchase

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  user
       ,priority
       ,Amount
  FROM
     (
      SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=o.user,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
             ,o.user 
             ,o.priority
             ,@prev_value := o.user
        FROM Orders o,
             (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
             (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
        where user IN (@usergroup) AND priority = @oldpriority 
       ORDER BY o.user, o.timestamp DESC
     ) subquery
 WHERE RowNumber > 2
```

I am not familir in Mysql, But i would say Rownumber will solve this. I have tried to solve this.

Above will select all older transcation, Exclude latest 2 transaction. example is [here](http://preilly.me/2011/11/11/mysql-row_number/)